# Python 2.7.14 on Kali Linux: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'

Tags: kali-linux, python, openssl

I was attempting to install w3af, and following their instructions, I ran the generated script to install the Python dependencies:

```
> sudo pip install pyClamd==0.3.15 PyGithub==1.21.0 GitPython==2.1.3
> pybloomfiltermmap==0.3.14 esmre==0.3.1 phply==0.9.1 nltk==3.0.1
> tblib==0.2.0 pdfminer==20140328 futures==2.1.5 pyOpenSSL==0.15.1
> ndg-httpsclient==0.3.3 pyasn1==0.2.3 lxml==3.4.4 scapy-real==2.2.0-dev
> guess-language==0.2 
>     cluster==1.1.1b3 msgpack-python==0.4.4 python-ntlm==1.0.1 halberd==0.2.4 darts.util.lru==0.5 Jinja2==2.7.3 vulndb==0.0.19
> markdown==2.6.1 psutil==2.2.1 mitmproxy==0.13
> ruamel.ordereddict==0.4.8 Flask==0.10.1 tldextract==1.7.2
> pebble==4.3.2 xdot==0.6
```

Now anytime I run pip, I get the following:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in
> from pip import main File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/init.py", line 21, in from
> pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import
> DependencyWarning File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/init.py", line 64, in
> vendored("cachecontrol") File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/init.py", line 36, in
> vendored import(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0) File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/init.py",
> line 9, in File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py",
> line 1, in File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py",
> line 4, in File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/init.py",
> line 52, in File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/init.py",
> line 59, in File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/init.py",
> line 32, in vendored File
> "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
> line 47, in File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/init.py", line 8, in
> from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in
> SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT AttributeError: 'module' object has no
> attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT
```

After some research, I believe it's due to the python openssl package, but all I've seen to do is reinstall it or upgrade, but I can't even run pip. At this point I'd like to just be able to use pip again, whether that means fixing the pyopenssl issue, or removing it, or reinstalling python altogether.

Thanks.

Comment: Please try harder to make your question readable.

Comment: The duplicate may solve the `pip` error , but it doesn't solve the `w3af` install problem.

Comment: The problem come from the installed `pyopenssl Version: 0.15.1`  it should be upgraded to [`pyOpenSSL 17.5.0`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL)

Comment: If you want to reopen a question, it is better if you explain what makes the difference crucial.